# ActiveRecord or SQL Statement for a 3 table query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need some help with the SQL statement or ActiveRecord query. I have 3 tables: Events, Incidents and Rules. There is 1-to-many relationship between Rules and Incidents, and 1-to-many relationship between Incidents and Events. I want to list all events that have triggered incidents due to a rule named "test". I am doing this in Rails. What is the SQL statement or ActiveRecord query to achieve my query.

Comment: `Rule.where(name: "test").first.incidents.includes(:events)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) to join tables. The query you need looks something like this:

```
Event.joins(:incident => :rule).where(:incidents => { :rules => { :name => 'test' } })
```